# How to get the Property Name and Value

Tags: c#

I would like to create a Handler that will take a lambda expression and return the name of the property that is passes in, and the value of the property.

Here is a sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var handler = new Handler();
        Contact contact = new Contact() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Travolta" };

        handler.DoSomething(x => contact.FirstName);
        handler.DoSomething(x => contact.LastName);

    }
}

public class Contact {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Handler {
    public void DoSomething(Func<object, object> func) {
        //Write the name of the property.
        Console.WriteLine(?);

        //Write the Value of the property.
        Console.WriteLine(?);
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What if the lambda contains something other than a property access, such as a method call?

Comment: With the lambda expression.  The problem I am trying to solve is that it could be used with many different classes/properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void DoSomething<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr, T target) {
        var pi = (PropertyInfo)(((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Member);
        Console.WriteLine(pi.Name);

        //Write the Value of the property.
        Console.WriteLine(expr.Compile()(target));
}
```

You'll have to pass the target to the method as well:

```
handler.DoSomething(x => contact.FirstName, x);
```

Comment: I would be interesting in seeing some profiling of code such as this. My guess is that it's just not worth it, with the call to `.Compile()` in there.

Comment: I agree, would rather not do that.  Perhaps just pass the value in directly as it will be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Some code from my library to get the property name.
Type `ExpressionUtils.GetPropertyName` in `Handler.DoSomething`

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of any argument given in the lambda expression.
    /// Sample:
    /// int argument = 10;
    /// string name = ExpressionUtils.GetName(() => argument);
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Argument type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="selector">Selector for the name of the argument</param>
    /// <returns>Argument name</returns>
    public static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> selector)
    {
        if (selector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        }

        MemberExpression member = RemoveUnary(selector.Body);
        if (member == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to get name from expression.");
        }

        return member.Member.Name;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the property given in the lambda expression.
    /// Sample:
    /// string propertyName = ExpressionUtils.GetPropertyName(() => x.Property);
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">Property type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertySelector">Selector for the name of the property</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetPropertyName<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        return GetPropertyNameImpl(propertySelector);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the property given in the lambda expression.
    /// Sample:
    /// <![CDATA[
    /// string propertyName = ExpressionUtils.GetPropertyName<Entity, int>(y => y.Property);
    /// ]]>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Entity containing the property type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">Propety type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertySelector">Selector for the name of the property</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetPropertyName<TEntity, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        return GetPropertyNameImpl(propertySelector);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the property given in the lambda expression.
    /// Sample:
    /// <![CDATA[
    /// string propertyName = ExpressionUtils.GetPropertyName<Entity, int>(y => y.Property);
    /// ]]>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Entity containing the property type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertySelector">Selector for the name of the property</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetPropertyName<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> propertySelector)
    {
        return GetPropertyNameImpl(propertySelector);
    }

    private static string GetPropertyNameImpl(LambdaExpression propertySelector)
    {
        if (propertySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertySelector");
        }

        MemberExpression member = RemoveUnary(propertySelector.Body);
        if (member == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression is not an access expression.");
        }

        var property = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Member in expression is not a property.");
        }

        return member.Member.Name;
    }

    private static MemberExpression RemoveUnary(Expression toUnwrap)
    {
        if (toUnwrap is UnaryExpression)
        {
            return ((UnaryExpression)toUnwrap).Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        return toUnwrap as MemberExpression;
    }
}
```

Comment: These are very nice and what I ended up using.